# Почему :after перекрывает родителя?

Tags: html, css, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Почему то :after перекрывает саму карточку, вроде бы с z-индексами всё норм. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://codepen.io/ilyabass/pen/KKpWwzG?editors=1100

Comment: У  after больше параметр z-index

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте прописать position: relative для элементов которые должны перекрывать (внутренним тем что в блоке mixin_card)

Answer (score 0):

Можете задать для after отрицательное значение: z-index: -1;

Но правильнее было бы явно указать каждому элементу его z-index

Comment: у меня тут всего 2 элемента грубо говоря, сама карточка, и after который её перекрывает непонятно почему, я задал для after белый фон, теперь он перекрывает и контент карточки.. z-index: -1 пробовал, но почему то наверх вылазит только контент карточки, а не вся карточка.. вот код карточки 
  https://codepen.io/ilyabass/pen/KKpWwzG?editors=1100

Comment: Если хотите выйти за карту, тогда помимо z-index: -1;  у after, удалите z-index: 2; у карты.

Comment: теперь :after исчез. Но на codepen всё работает, это может быть из-за того что у меня вся вёрстка обёрнута в .wrapper{overflow: hidden;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;}??

Comment: @user367009 ближайшему родителю карточки добавьте position: relative; z-index: 0; или любой другой индекс, он будет держать ваш after и не даст провалится за документ

Comment: теперь только текст карточки появился, но after теперь перекрывает саму карточку

Comment: @user367009 может вы просто сделаете 2 фона и оставите карточку в покое?